# How to solve a system of equations with sin and cos?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$50= 35\cos(x) +25\cos(y) $

$0= 35\sin(x)+25\sin(y)  $

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had any thoughts yourself?

Comment: yes I was going to try using the sum to product identities but because of the constants in front of all the terms I couldn't get it to work

Comment: The question seems to contain sufficient context to get $x = -\arcsin(\frac{2\sqrt{66}}{35}) + 2 \pi m$ and $y = \arccos(\frac{19}{25}) + 2 \pi l$ where $m$ and $l$ are integers that can vary independently. Until someone specifies the missing context, here is the answer: http://mathb.in/48471

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches.  You could just use $\cos x = \pm \sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$ and get a system in just $\sin x, \sin y$.  In this case I would square the two equations and add, then square them and subtract.  Magic happens.